# PHP update SQL from multiple HTML checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

So, I need to make sure this sets the right parameters to the DB when pressing  the buttons. I just want to get the calls and comparisons right so it does what it should when I hit the buttons. There should be one delete button for each row from database, and update page when I press it.

It should be possible to update the text/numbers in the forms presented by MySQL by changing the forms and press Save-button, then refresh the page.

```
$counter = 1;

if(isset($_POST['save']) and something is changed from the forms compared to DB) {
Update MySQL

Refresh page
<script>
window.location.replace("thispage.php");
</script>

}

if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
DELETE MySQL

Refresh page
<script>
window.location.replace("thispage.php");
</script>

}

echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Namn</td><td>Platser</td><td>Fullbokad</td><td>Ta bort</td></tr>";

$sqlListSections = "SELECT * FROM avdelningar WHERE user = {$_SESSION['id']}";
$queryListSections = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlListSections);
$del = [];

while($rowListSections = mysqli_fetch_array($queryListSections)) 
{   

    if($counter%2) 
    {
        echo "\n<tr bgcolor=#F1F1F2>\n\n";
    }else
    {
        echo "\n<tr bgcolor=#FFFFFF>\n\n";
    }

    $counter++;



    echo "

    <td>".$rowListSections['id']."</td>
    <td>
        <input type=text value=".$rowListSections['namn']."></td>

    <td>
        <input type=text value=".$rowListSections['platser']."></td>
    <td>";
    if($rowListSections['prio'] == 1) 
    {
        echo "<select name=platser>
            <option selected value=".$rowListSections['prio'].">".$rowListSections['prio']."</option>
            <option value='0'>0</option>".$rowListSections['prio'];
    }elseif($rowListSections['prio'] == 0)
    {
        echo "<select name=platser>
            <option selected value=".$rowListSections['prio'].">".$rowListSections['prio']."</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>".$rowListSections['prio'];
    }
    echo "</td>
    <td>
        <form method=post action=thispage.php>
        <input type=submit value=Delete name=del>";
    </td>
    </form>
    </tr>";


}

echo "<form method=post action=thispage.php>
<input type=submit value=Save name=save>";
`
```

Comment: can you please give detail idea about this? what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to mark those sections I want to delete, press Save button and delete all that are checked and show the new result

Answer (score 1):

in your checkbox change naming as array.

`<input type=checkbox name="del[]" value={$rowListSections['id']}>`

like

```
echo $rowListSections["id"].' '.$rowListSections["namn"].' '.$rowListSections["platser"].' '.
```

$rowListSections["prio"].'';

and in your `if(isset($_POST))` you can get a `del` array so you can loop this array like below.

```
foreach($del as $val){
    $id = $val;
    $sql_query_for_update = "update table_name set field = 1 where id= '$id' ";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I can't write name=del[] without errors in my checkbox row.
Could you give me all the code example?

Comment: I still dont understand. I cant write del[] in <checkbox>? And is that an array, without the $?

Comment: Yes! if you put [] in name, it will be treated as array. for eg: if you submit this form then you will get all the checked checkboxes are as an array. `( $_POST['del'] = [0 => 'val', 1  => 'val1']`   )

Comment: let me know if you don't get this :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to put it in like that yesterday, but i got an error msg. So is it supposed to be echo "<input type=checkbox name=".del[].">"; or echo "<input type=checkbox name=del[]>";?

Comment: It is better if you use the quotes between names. please use the same as I updated in answer, or In my opinion, you can just print the Html part without echo instead.

Comment: close PHP tag before and after HTML. like `?><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="<?php echo $rowListSections['id']; ?>" ><?php`

Comment: Do i need to define $del = [] before i use it in checkbox <>?

Comment: no need to declare or define it. Just use the same as above. that is enough.

Comment: ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value=<?php echo $rowListSections['id'];
 echo "></td>";
}

echo "<form method=post action=managesections.php>
<input type=submit value=Spara/Uppdatera name=saveDel>";

 foreach($del as $val){
 echo $del;
    $sql_query_for_update = "update table_name set field = 1 where id= '$val' ";
}

And I get error message:
Notice: Undefined variable: del in C:\wamp64\www\managesections.php

Comment: No this is wrong. Show me your file, i will help you how to add these, update ur file in question.

Comment: That's the code I'm using to write out the data from SQL.

Comment: Maybe I should use buttons instead for delete, and refresh the page when button isset. And then just make sure it updates when something else is changed, I guess I will need a comparison to the SQL when the Save button is clicked.

Comment: try this `https://paiza.io/projects/vVS-K75r3YI3gccyIs_Kxw #paizaIO` it is i edited for you. i think it is what you needed, if not pls tell me.

Comment: Looks Great! I will try it later tonight when I get home! I hope The del[] will work now! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realize it was just supposed to be a string in the <checkbox> tag and be treated as an array first in the $_POST. Now I think I get it!

I would like to do the same with 2 <input type=text> and 1 <select><option></option>. I want to check if they have changed value and in that case update only that form in MySQL. Would you mind help me with that too? Thanks alot! And maybe you should upload the code here instead if others may find it useful?

Comment: @Dev do you have any solution to that? Should I catch the POST's in the same if(isset($_POST['save'])) ?

Comment: @RobinJakobsson do you want to save the modified fields only?

Comment: Yes, $sql = "UPDATE sections SET {$row['column']} = {$_POST['form']}"

Comment: @RobinJakobsson can you show me your complete code? I am not able to build a code that matches your requirement. if you show me your example so i can edit with that

Comment: It's the $rowListSections[namn, id, prio] in my code above (first post) I want to match to the database. So if user has edited one of the field I want to discover that and update the database. I think you should have all that you need in my code on top of this page.

Comment: Check my above link, i have updated there, i can't add those in my answer, because your question and my answers will be different to other users and they seem confused. Here i have added a new input type fileld and a javascript function, please let me know if you have dbt in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I cant find it when I press your link. It seems to be the old solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it later! But as it seems, this updates even if I delete one character/edit the field and then change it back to the original? Isn't it a better solution to compare to the old column in the database, or did you do this to avoid unnescessary sql-querys?

Comment: Yes! comparing with the existing data from the database is not a nice method, as you said, it will update the table even when you roll back your edit. but it is okay.

Comment: I have a problem. $value1 and $value2 is returning the right values. But it doesn't update my table, then I realized it could be because I don't refer to the ID of the 'avdelning' (section) I want to update. Here is my current $sql row. $sql = "UPDATE avdelningar SET namn = {$value1}, platser = {$value2} WHERE id = ";

Comment: When I tried to edit more than 2 fields it changed ALL my 'name' columns to "-96" and all 'platser' columns to "2".

Comment: Your update query should be modified, please print the sql in your loop and identdidy the error. the ID also should get from the array as we get the value 1 and 2.

Comment: I printed $value1, $value2, $key. And i had to change $key to $key + 1. But it still doesn't work if my ID is 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, then it will just be 1,2,3,4,5 in the array.

Comment: @RobinJakobsson the key is not your ID, you can get the ID by adding a hidden type `<input type="hidded" value="<?php echo $rowListSections['id']; ?>" name="id[]" >` somewhere in your loop and `$_POST['id']['$key']` to get it.

Comment: But isn't that what the status[] in your code does? Can I use $_POST['status']['id'] to get the ID?

Comment: Your codeexample works, but I can't update the text-fields with letters, only numbers.

Comment: do you know why? :)

Comment: try hangout me at sanjundev@gmail.com, I will ready to help you, but it is not good method to have a larger comment conversation in StackOverflow.